# Maven does not download dependency

Tags: java, maven

I just added directjngine to my maven project dependencie list the following way:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.softwarementors.extjs</groupId>
        <artifactId>directjngine</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

However after I do a maven update on the project, it says that this dependency is still missing. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: have you tried to run maven with debug?

Comment: [Did you include the repository?](https://maven-repository.com/artifact/com.softwarementors.extjs/directjngine/2.2)

Comment: Thanks dude, I'm still new to java development